# LVM filesystem is full, cannot update system amongst other things

Tags: centos, filesystems, rhel, lvm

I am running a RHEL 7 server with a license from my university. I am running it on a bare metal server in a local place on my university. I originally installed RHEL 7 with LVM on my hard drive (there is a 2TB HDD in the system). I started noticing that I was greeted with this message on login after a while.

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/.colorlsXXX’: No space left on device
-bash: $TMP: ambiguous redirect
```

If I would try updating the system, I would be greeted with a very similar message by `yum`. Upon evaluating the space left on my filesystem, the issue was apparent.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   50G   50G   20K 100% /
devtmpfs                12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   12G  4.0K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   12G  8.8M   12G   1% /run
tmpfs                   12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2              494M  170M  325M  35% /boot
/dev/sda1              200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home  1.8T  843G  958G  47% /home
```

The `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` part of my filesystem, where the root directory is located, is out of room and is causing issues with my system. Inside of LVM, is there a way I can resolve or fix this issue without reinstalling the operating system? Ideally, any other solution than reinstalling would be preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just extend the size of your logical volume.

```
lvextend -r -L +1G /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't find this when searching, thanks. However, I have another issue when I run this command.
`$ sudo lvextend -r -L +25G /dev/mapper/rhel-root`
  `Couldn't create temporary archive name.`
  `Volume group "rhel" metadata archive failed.`
Any ideas what is going on now?

Comment: Delete some space in /dev/mapper/rhel-root volume. LVM needs to write archives in /etc/lvm/backup, /etc/lvm/arvice... etc.

Comment: I did this, but now it complains about something else. For example, if I try to add 1GB to `/dev/mapper/rhel-root`, I now get `Insufficient free space: 256 extents needed, but only 16 available`. I now have 49GB free in the volume…

Comment: You have got only 16 extents free...  you are ran out of space in "rhel" volumen group. Check it out: `vgs rhe`